# Movie from the 80's where almost everyone dies

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie plot was there was an accident that wiped out life except if you happened to die at the exact same time when the accident took place. The movie centered around a character who if I remember correctly worked at the facility where the accident took place.

Sound familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Quiet Earth. 1985 
This movie has always been one of my favorites.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quiet_Earth

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089869/?ref_=nv_sr_1

Comment: Yup, that is it, thanks!